# Define starting range based on cellvalue

Tags: excel, dynamic, count, range, countif

In the picture example I want to count each column that is empty (Or has the value 0) in each row. I started with the function countif but I need the range to be dynamic instead of doing a manual job on every row, as each row has a different starting point.

Could somebody help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Try this array formula (enter with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

```
=SUM(IF(INDEX($B1:$N1,1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK($B1:$N1),0)):N1,0,1))
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Note that `MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK($B1:$N1),0)` is the dynamic part which checks where the calculation range should actually start (i.e. it ignores the first few blank cells).

Comment: You're welcome Jerry. Your approach was correct and you could also achieve the same using `COUNTIF`, but I found `SUM` approach easier to write :-) take care